# url formatting with beginning & ending date & time using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, url, date-formatting

I'm using Pandas to generate a list of dates and times within a specified range to get query an API. My aim is to query weeks or months on per-hour basis.

```
time_range = pd.date_range('20180601T07:00:0000', '20180701T07:00:0000', freq='H')
time_range = time_range.strftime("%Y%m%d"+'T%H:00-0000')
```

yields a list of times in the desired list format. Where I'm encountering difficulty is that the URL is formatted...

```
startdatetime=20180601T07:00-0000&enddatetime=20180601T08:00-0000
```

I understand I need to start with values 0 & 1 from the Pandas list but I don't how to cycle through. Should I be thinking of a dictionary like...

```
{date1:[hour1, hour2, etc...], date2:[hour1, hour2, etc...], ...}
```

and use a .format where startdatetime={1}&enddatetime={2} ?
or should it be more like a for loop...

```
for date in date_range:
    url = 'http://somename?startdatetime={date}&enddatetime{date2}'
    urldate = url.format(date=date)
    urldate2 = url.format(date2=date + 1)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand clearly, you want to iterate from a starting date/time (2018-06-01 07:00) to an ending date/time (2018-07-01 07:00) with a step of one hour. And produce an URL with date/time intervals of one hour.

I don’t know why you use Panda for that when you can do it with the standard library, like that:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 7)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 7)
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

fmt = 'http://somename?startdatetime={date1:%Y%m%d%H:00-0000}&enddatetime{date2:%Y%m%d%H:00-0000}'

while start < end:
    date1 = start
    date2 = start + delta
    url = fmt.format(date1=date1, date2=date2)
    print(url)
    start = date2
```

You get:

```
http://somename?startdatetime=2018060107:00-0000&enddatetime2018060108:00-0000
http://somename?startdatetime=2018060108:00-0000&enddatetime2018060109:00-0000
http://somename?startdatetime=2018060109:00-0000&enddatetime2018060110:00-0000
http://somename?startdatetime=2018060110:00-0000&enddatetime2018060111:00-0000
...
```

In the loop, I work with date instances. I use a format string, like “{date2:%Y%m%d%H:00-0000}” to format the date and time in the required format.

Notice that the *date_range()* function is easy to implement with the standard library:

```
def date_range(start, end, delta):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start = start + delta
```

To get the list of dates with an interval of one hour, you can do:

```
dates = list(date_range(
    datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 7),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 7),
    datetime.timedelta(hours=1)))
```

Then, the solution becomes:

```
fmt = 'http://somename?startdatetime={date1:%Y%m%d%H:00-0000}&enddatetime{date2:%Y%m%d%H:00-0000}'

for date1, date2 in zip(dates[:-1], dates[1:]):
    url = fmt.format(date1=date1, date2=date2)
    print(url)
```

The trick is to use the *zip()* function with the list of dates shifted with one item to get the couples of dates.

Comment: Thank you - that was exactly what I needed, I guess I need to understand
    timedelta

Comment: Is there a benefit in using the zip version vs. the timedelta version>

Comment: Both use `timedelta`. The first one uses a while loop, the second one use a for loop. Efficiency for the first, readability for the second. It’s up to you to decide.